# How do i create a grid of randomised labelled buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create an application that accepts response from a user in terms of button presses. As part of this project, i want to create a grid of  3x3 or 4x4 grid of big buttons equally spaced and equal sized and which will have labels containing a combination of two alphabet between A-D e.g. AB, AC, BC etc in a random order

I can create buttons in html but im fairly new to coding so things that may seem obvious are probably difficult. The functionalities i want includes recording start time a grid appears to when a target button e.g. DC is pressed (stop time), trigger when the grid appears (new grid of buttons), randomise the appearance of buttons on the grid, have one consistent target button to be pressed on all interfaces.

Has anyone done this before or can anyone share a stripped down example. Can someone point me in the right direction in terms of documentation or coding environment that perhaps I skipped over? Any comments or code will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Tutorial should be a good starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Also http://jsfiddle.net/ is good tool to play with the code you write

Comment: I have been through the tutorial of w3 schools i must admit its good starting point. Any help on the designing the buttons and a little code on capturing the response time will greatly appreciated

Comment: Stackoverflow is used by professional programmers. http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It's not a good place to ask about designing buttons. Please accept this answer and use Google to answer rest of your questions.